# Prestashop address format with title /how to add title in address format for Prestashop 1.6.3

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

Is it possible to add title (and title needs to be bold) to the corresponding fields for address where the address is been shown/displayed.

The address format is coming from SELECT * FROM `ps_address_format` .But how to add title like name address , Phone no etc ?As shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: On which page are you referring?

Comment: Billing information page , before the Proceed to check out button is clicked on that page i need modification

Comment: So you have the classic checkout (5 steps) right?

Comment: yes 5 steps  but modified it to two steps

Answer (score 0):

In the ps_address_format table, the address formats are stored country wise, you can simply edit the format for the desired country as follows:

Current Format (for example):

firstname lastname company vat_number address1 address2 postcode city Country:name phone phone_mobile

Add 'alias' to your desired position and save.

Comment: I tried  like this  but the title is not appearing  my query= UPDATE `ps_address_format` SET `format` = 'Name:firstname lastname Passport No:passport_no Address:address1 address2 City:city Country:name Phone:phone Phone Mobile :phone_mobile' WHERE `ps_address_format`.`id_country` = 217;